# Custom Validator - Pass in Parameter

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, customvalidator

I have this custom validator that checks if the `categories` field of my form has a value, and if it does, then if the `mealTypes` field is null, then sets `mealTypes` to be invalid. It is placed just outside of my component:

```
function validateMealType(findForm: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: boolean]} {
    if (findForm.get("mealCategoryChosen").value) {
        if (!findForm.get("mealTypes").value) {
            return { "invalidMealTypes": true };
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

And I use it in my component to validate my components form:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.findForm = this.formBuilder.group({
        categories: null,
        mealTypes: [null, Validators.required],
        mealCategoryChosen: null,
        distanceNumber: null,
        distanceUnit: 'kilometers',
        keywords: null,
    }, validateMealType);
}
```

And it works. [Here is the plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/2xMxtEpJLvBnsfcdCil7?p=preview). Many thanks to the answerer of my last question for the plunker.

I just have one more acceptance criteria now.

I have this boolean property on the component:

`private mealSelected: boolean = false;`

At the moment I set `mealTypes` to be invalid if `categories` has a value and `mealtypes` is null.

I need to only set mealTypes to be invalid if `categories` has a value and `mealTypes` is null AND `mealSelected` === true. Is it possible to add a boolean parameter to the validateMealType function and pass in my component property `mealSelected`?? How would I do that? Could someone update [my plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/2xMxtEpJLvBnsfcdCil7?p=preview) to do that? I'm finding the answers on here with how to add a parameter to a custom validator quite hard to fully understand and correctly apply to my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create new `FormControl` to represent your current `mealSelected`

```
this.findForm = new FormGroup({
  mealTypes : new FormControl(null, Validators.Required),
  categories : new FormControl(null),
  mealSelected : new FormControl(false) // <-- here is the new form control
}, validateMealType);
```

You do not have to associate the new `FormControl` to any `html input`, and you could update the value programmatically

```
this.findForm.controls["mealSelected"].setValue(true) //programatically set the value
```

> I need to only set mealTypes to be invalid if categories has a value and mealTypes is null AND mealSelected === true.

Here is how the custom validator would be

```
if (
    findForm.controls["categories"].value &&
    !findForm.controls["mealTypes"].value &&
    findForm.controls["mealSelected"].value === true
) 
{
    return {"invalidMealTypes": true}; 
}
```

Example [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/FHVjpeUbmJRJGNfHdxD0?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks. It doesn't work in my app. I don't have `[formControl]="findForm.controls['categories']"` in my app because I use model driven forms. My form controls are buried in custom components so I can't do `[formControl]="findForm.controls['categories']"` on them. Is it possible that your plunker can work without `[formControl]="findForm.controls['categories']"`?

Comment: @Beniamino_Baggins You are not using `FormBuilder`, are you?

Comment: Categories is required also. Kind of seems like in the plunker adding the required validator to categories isn't working which is weird.

Comment: ohhhh wait yeah I'm using form builder. I think that is an issue right. I will fix that

Comment: Weirdly your solution to my first question works, while still using `FormBuilder`. I changed my code back to your first answer but using `FormBuilder` as that is working the best so far. Categories `required` validator is working and mealTypes validator is working too - I just need to add in the `mealSelected` to the custom validator again.